# Is there a way to use endnote with bibliometrix?

Tags: excel, txt, bibtex, bibliography

I have a bunch of groups in endnote that I want to export to bibliometrix however, I am having trouble finding a format that bibliometrix will except.

I have tried exporting the groups the excel using a tab delimited format

Comment: Did you try comma-delimited format aka CSV ?

Comment: I did try this using a smaller file. It looks like the issue is not the format or the delimiter but rather bibliometrix does not support "homemade" excel files as per their website.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.